# Помогите отсортировать массив в коде

Tags: c, массивы, сортировка

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define N 5
int main()
{
    float A[N];
    int on;
    int max = INT_MIN;
    int min = INT_MAX;
    int K=0;
    int MaxIndex = 0;
    int MinIndex = 0;
    int res = 1;
    for(int i =0; i<N; i++)
    {
        scanf("%f",&A[i]);
    }
     while(on!=3)
    {
    printf("menu:\n");
    printf("1-persha zada4a\n2-druga zada4a\n3-exit\n");
    printf("vedit' nomer:");

          scanf("%d",&on);
          switch (on)
        {

            case 1:
            for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)
            {
                if(A[i]<0)
                {
                    K+=A[i];
                } 
            }
           printf("suma vid'yemnih 4isel = %d\n",K);
           break;
           case 2:
           for(int i = 0;  i<N; i++) 
           {
                if(A[i]>max)
                {
                    max= A[i];
                    MaxIndex = i;
                } 
        else if(A[i]<min)
        {
             min = A[i];
             MinIndex = i;
        }
     }
     if (MaxIndex>MinIndex)
     {
         for (int j =MinIndex+1; j <MaxIndex; j++)
         {
             res=res*A[j];
         }
     }
     else if (MaxIndex<MinIndex)
     {
         for (int j =MaxIndex+1; j <MinIndex; j++)
         {
             res=res*A[j];
         }
     }
     printf("%d\n",res);
     break;
        }
    }
     system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Какие-то идеи, как надо  сортировать у вас есть? Напишите хотя бы в комментарии к той части кода, где просите помощи

Comment: третим кейсом написать код, чтобы вывело сортированый массив, по отдельности работало, а когда попробовал написать вместе то ничего не выходит

Comment: вот код для сортировки, только нужно поместить его в тот что выше 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define N 5
int main()
{
int A[N];
int i,k;
int min1,Imin;
 for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &A[i]);
    }
for(k = 0; k < N-1 ; k++)
{
min1=A[k];
Imin=k;
for (i = k+1; i < N ; i++)
{
if (A[i]<min1)
{
min1=A[i];
Imin=i;
}
}
A[Imin]=A[k];
A[k]=min1;
}
for(i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
printf("\t%d",A[i]);
 
getch();
return 0;
}

Comment: Т.е. вы сортируете методом поиска минимума. Отлично. Оптимизируйте код, убрав лишние переменные `min1` и `lmin`. Просто вместо `min1` во внутреннем цикле по `i` используйте `A[k]`. Т.о. когда во внутреннем цикле встречается элемент, который меньше `A[k]` вы обменяете значениями `A[k]` и этот элемент. Вот так:  `if (A[i] < A[k]) { int t = A[k]; A[k] = A[i]; A[i] = t;}` И все будет ОК

Comment: огромное спасибо! сортировка работает, но почему то перестал работать второй case

Comment: Это уж вы сами повнимательней посмотрите на код. А лучше оформлять такие подзадачи в виде функций. Функции уже изучали?

Comment: С таким еще не знаком.

Comment: Значит пора почитать о функциях. Это в принципе такие же штуки, как `printf()`, который вы вызываете, но вы сами их пишете

Answer (score 1):

```
int a[10],temp;
for (int i=0;i<9;i++)
for (int j=0; j<9;j++)
    if (a[j] > a[j+1]) {                
       tmp = a[j];
       a[j] = a[j+1];
       a[j+1] = temp;
   }
```

Если я не ошибаюсь, то вот ^ алгоритм пузырьковой сортировки массива(по возрастанию).